# Trim POST value on a function

Tags: php, function, pass-by-reference, trim

I have a function which verify if all necessary parameters are set and then trim these params.
Is it possible? How can/should I pass these parameters per reference?

```
$error = false;
$error = array();

$posts = array('first_name', 'last_name', 'email',
               'telephone', 'address', 'CAP', 'city', 'comments'
                //many others
                );

$post_error = dieOrTrim(&$posts, &$error);

echo '<pre>';
echo '0'.$_POST['first_name'].'0<br />';
var_dump($error);              
var_dump($_POST);
echo '</pre>';
die();
```

FUNCTION:

```
function dieOrTrim(&$param) {
    foreach($param as &$p){
        if(!isset($_POST[$p])){
            $error[] = '$_POST['.$p.']';
            $post_error = 'ERROR';
            return $post_error;
        }else{
            $_POST[$p] = trim($_POST[$p]);
        }
    }
}
```

Entering ' Name ' on first_name field returns:

```
0 Name 0

array(0) {
}

array(18) {
  ["first_name"]=>
  string(6) " Name "
  ["last_name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["email"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["telephone"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["address"]=>
  string(3) "+41"
  ["CAP"]=>
  string(3) "(0)"
  ["city"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["comments"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["etc"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["etc"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["etc"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["etc"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["etc"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["etc"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["etc"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["etc"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["etc"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["etc"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [PHP need to trim all the $\_POST variables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4710440/php-need-to-trim-all-the-post-variables)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are there any values that should not be trimmed?

Else you could just trim all values using [array_map](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php), if `$_POST` is not [empty](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php):

```
if(!empty($_POST)) {
  $_POST = array_map("trim", $_POST);
}
```

Hope that helps, not so much code :)

Comment: Thank you, this is the fastest and best solution. I'll only mantain my function to verify that all parameters are setted.

Answer (score 1):

The problem I see in your function is that you return immediately after you check `!isset($_POST[$p])`.  I believe you want to continue on to the next item and operate on that accordingly.

```
function dieOrTrim($param) {
    $post_error = '';

    foreach($param as $p){
        if(!isset($_POST[$p])){
            $post_error = 'ERROR';
            continue;
        }

        // Trim $_POST[$p] if it's set
        $_POST[$p] = trim($_POST[$p]);
    }

    return $post_error;
}
```

Also, you don't need to pass these by reference since you are not modifying any of the passed parameters.

Comment: Thank you! No, I'd like to stop at the first inoccurence of $_POST[$p], this is my intention. The problem is that the $_POST[$p] parameters are not trimmed when testing them after the function

Comment: How does your input look like, i.e. `var_dump($_POST)`?

Comment: I was interested in before just to make sure that it die not `ERROR`ed out early.  But please post both before and after in your question.

Comment: Posted, I didn't get error because after the function I post `$post_error` and `die()` if $post_error is not false anymore... I edited my code;

Comment: In the `var_dump` you've posted, all inputs are already trimmed, how are you testing this?