# Applying array_map recursively (array_walk_recursive?)

Tags: php, arrays, recursion

I have an associative array that is I am creating from an ODBC query with the following code:

```
        while ($row=odbc_fetch_array($oexec)) {
        if(empty($group[$row['gmm']])) {
            $group[$row['gmm']] = array();
        }
        if(empty($group[$row['gmm']][$row['acctg_dept_nbr'] . " - " . $row['acctg_dept_desc']])) {
            $group[$row['gmm']][$row['acctg_dept_nbr'] . " - " . $row['acctg_dept_desc']] = array();
        }
        if(empty($group[$row['gmm']][$row['acctg_dept_nbr'] . " - " . $row['acctg_dept_desc']][$row['dept_catg_grp_desc']])) {
            $group[$row['gmm']][$row['acctg_dept_nbr'] . " - " . $row['acctg_dept_desc']][$row['dept_catg_grp_desc']] = array();
        }
        if(empty($group[$row['gmm']][$row['acctg_dept_nbr'] . " - " . $row['acctg_dept_desc']][$row['dept_catg_grp_desc']][$row['dept_category_desc']])) {
            $group[$row['gmm']][$row['acctg_dept_nbr'] . " - " . $row['acctg_dept_desc']][$row['dept_catg_grp_desc']][$row['dept_category_desc']] = array();
        }
        if(empty($group[$row['gmm']][$row['acctg_dept_nbr'] . " - " . $row['acctg_dept_desc']][$row['dept_catg_grp_desc']][$row['dept_category_desc']][$row['dept_subcatg_desc']])) {
            $group[$row['gmm']][$row['acctg_dept_nbr'] . " - " . $row['acctg_dept_desc']][$row['dept_catg_grp_desc']][$row['dept_category_desc']][$row['dept_subcatg_desc']] = array();
        }
        $group[$row['gmm']][$row['acctg_dept_nbr'] . " - " . $row['acctg_dept_desc']][$row['dept_catg_grp_desc']][$row['dept_category_desc']][$row['dept_subcatg_desc']]['total_ty_yest_sales'] = $row['total_ty_yest_sales'];
        $group[$row['gmm']][$row['acctg_dept_nbr'] . " - " . $row['acctg_dept_desc']][$row['dept_catg_grp_desc']][$row['dept_category_desc']][$row['dept_subcatg_desc']]['total_wo_dotcom_ty_yest_sales'] = $row['total_wo_dotcom_ty_yest_sales'];
        $group[$row['gmm']][$row['acctg_dept_nbr'] . " - " . $row['acctg_dept_desc']][$row['dept_catg_grp_desc']][$row['dept_category_desc']][$row['dept_subcatg_desc']]['east_ty_yest_sales'] = $row['east_ty_yest_sales'];
        $group[$row['gmm']][$row['acctg_dept_nbr'] . " - " . $row['acctg_dept_desc']][$row['dept_catg_grp_desc']][$row['dept_category_desc']][$row['dept_subcatg_desc']]['central_ty_yest_sales'] = $row['central_ty_yest_sales'];
        $group[$row['gmm']][$row['acctg_dept_nbr'] . " - " . $row['acctg_dept_desc']][$row['dept_catg_grp_desc']][$row['dept_category_desc']][$row['dept_subcatg_desc']]['west_ty_yest_sales'] = $row['west_ty_yest_sales'];
        $group[$row['gmm']][$row['acctg_dept_nbr'] . " - " . $row['acctg_dept_desc']][$row['dept_catg_grp_desc']][$row['dept_category_desc']][$row['dept_subcatg_desc']]['dotcom_ty_yest_sales'] = $row['dotcom_ty_yest_sales'];

    }
```

This gives me an array where:

```
$myArray = Array(GMM => Array(acctg_dept_nbr => Array(dept_category_desc => Array(dept_subcatg_desc => Array(value1,value2,value3)))))
```

I want to sum the values at every level. So for every acctg_dept_nbr[dept_category_desc][dept_subcatg_desc] I want to sum value1,value2,value3. Same for the GMM level and down to the dept_subcatg_desc level. Summing the dept_subcatg_desc level wasn't a problem. I dug around and found how to sum the dept_category_desc level, but am having trouble applying that method recursively.

Here is the code that puts the values into a table:

```
foreach($group as $gmm => $acctg_dept_nbrs) {
        echo "<tr class=\"header\">
        <td>" . $gmm . "</td>\n";

        foreach ($acctg_dept_nbrs as $acctg_dept_nbr => $dept_catg_grp_descs) {
                        echo "<tr class=\"header\">\n
            <td style=\"padding-left: 1em;\">" . $acctg_dept_nbr . "</td>\n";

            foreach($dept_catg_grp_descs as $dept_catg_grp_desc => $dept_category_descs) {
                echo "<tr class=\"header\">\n
                <td style=\"padding-left: 2em;\">" . $dept_catg_grp_desc . "</td>\n";
                                    //echo "<td>" . array_sum(array_walk_recursive($dept_category_descs,function($item) {return $item['total_ty_yest_sales'];})) . "</td>";
                foreach($dept_category_descs as $dept_category_desc => $dept_subcatg_descs) {
                    echo "<tr class=\"header\">\n
                    <td style=\"padding-left: 3em;\">" . $dept_category_desc . "</td>\n";
                                            echo "<td>" . array_sum(array_map(function($item) {return $item['total_ty_yest_sales'];},$dept_subcatg_descs)) . "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>" . array_sum(array_map(function($item) {return $item['east_ty_yest_sales'];},$dept_subcatg_descs)) . "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>" . array_sum(array_map(function($item) {return $item['central_ty_yest_sales'];},$dept_subcatg_descs)) . "</td>";
                                            echo "<td>" . array_sum(array_map(function($item) {return $item['west_ty_yest_sales'];},$dept_subcatg_descs)) . "</td>";
                    foreach($dept_subcatg_descs as $dept_subcatg_desc => $values) {
                                                echo "<tr>\n
                                                    <td style=\"padding-left: 4em;\">" . $dept_subcatg_desc . "</td>\n";
                                                $sum = $values['total_ty_yest_sales'];
                                                echo "<td>".$sum."</td>";
                                                $sum = $values['east_ty_yest_sales'];
                                                echo "<td>".$sum."</td>";
                                                $sum = $values['central_ty_yest_sales'];
                                                echo "<td>".$sum."</td>";
                                                $sum = $values['west_ty_yest_sales'];
                                                echo "<td>".$sum."</td>";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The commented out line is the problem for me now. This:

```
array_sum(array_map(function($item) {return $item['west_ty_yest_sales'];},$dept_subcatg_descs))
```

works fine at that level, but not at the higher levels. I have also tried to tweak this function to no avail:

```
function array_map_recursive($callback, $array) {
    foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
        if (is_array($array[$key])) {
            $array[$key] = array_map_recursive($callback, $array[$key]);
        }
        else {
            $array[$key] = call_user_func($callback, $array[$key]);
        }
    }
    return $array;
}
```

How can I make this work so that regardless of level it will dig down and sum the values for that portion of the array?

Comment: You are sure you callback is returning a value?  there doesn't seem to be anything wrong with this recursive function.

Comment: If I use: array_sum(array_map_recursive(function($item) {return $item['total_ty_yest_sales'];},$dept_category_descs))
I get an illegal string offset error. The callback works here:
array_sum(array_map(function($item) {return $item['total_ty_yest_sales'];},$dept_subcatg_descs))

Comment: your passing an anonymous / lambda function as a string into your callback parameter, so call_user_func won't work like this, as it will try to call a function called `function($item){...}`  you should define your callback separately, and pass the name of it in.

Comment: Thanks, I think I just caught on to that. Let's see if I can figure it out...

Comment: I think you probably can do it by replacing `call_user_func($callback, $array[$key]);` with simply `$callback($array[$key]);`

Comment: I've tried both methods. I'm still getting an illegal offset error.  
    `function myCallback($item,$field) {  
        return $item[$field];  
    }  
    function array_map_recursive($array,$field) {  
        foreach ($array as $key => $value) {  
            if (is_array($array[$key])) {  
                $array[$key] = array_map_recursive($array[$key],$field);  
            }  
            else {  
                $array[$key] = myCallback($array[$key],$field);
            }
        }
        return $array;
    }
array_sum(array_map_recursive($dept_category_descs,"total_ty_yest_sales"))`

Answer (score 39):

```
function array_map_recursive($callback, $array)
{
  $func = function ($item) use (&$func, &$callback) {
    return is_array($item) ? array_map($func, $item) : call_user_func($callback, $item);
  };

  return array_map($func, $array);
}
```

Comment: Can you write a implementation?

Comment: Please specify what needs to be implemented?

Comment: if i give you an $array => ["a"=>1,"b"=>"2"] and if i want value of a+b then,
how do i use it and what will be the code line for the function
should i write $sum = array_map("array_map_recursive", $array)
I want to exactly how do i use the function what is the $callback? 

Or should i just pass my own function in the place of callbace ?
like 
function sum($p1,$p2){ return $p1+$p2;}

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce 
https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php

Answer (score 2):

```
function array_map_recursive($callback, $array)
{
    if(is_array($callback)){
        foreach ($callback as $function){
            $array = array_map_recursive($function, $array);
        }
        return $array;
    }

    $func = function ($item) use (&$func, &$callback) {
        return is_array($item) ? array_map($func, $item) : call_user_func($callback, $item);
    };

    return array_map($func, $array);
}
```

This way you can call the function passing more functions.. ex:

`$rowData = array_map_recursive(['utf8_decode', 'trim'], $rowData);`

Or simple call just one:

`$rowData = array_map_recursive('trim', $rowData);`

Answer (score 1):

It can be a little difficult if we add multiple arrays to the function. But with only one, there is no problem at all.

```
      function array_map_recursive(&$arr, $fn) {
            return array_map(function($item) use($fn){
                return is_array($item) ? array_map_recursive($item, $fn) : $fn($item);
            }, $arr);
        }

      $array = array_map_recursive($array, function($item){
            //TODO logic here
      });
```

Answer (score 1):

filter_var can essentially be used to accomplish this

```
function array_map_recursive(callable $func, array $array) {
    return filter_var($array, FILTER_CALLBACK, ['options' => $func]);
}
```

There is one big drawback...
The callback will receive the value as a string.
and the leafs can't be objects